# Unable to get the numerical result for a tanh function in Sympy

Tags: sympy

I am a python newbie. I am trying to get the two numerical results of the convection formula, but the best code I've created outputs a symbolic list containing the 'Lc' parameter, and not the expected numerical result. Anyone could give me a helping hand, please?

```
from sympy import var, tanh, solve

def convection ():

    m = 0.9
    Lc = var('Lc')
    rend = 0.8

    f = tanh(m*Lc)/(m*Lc)-rend

    return solve(f,[m,Lc,rend],positive=True)

    # Gotten : [(0.900000000000000, Lc, 1.11111111111111*tanh(0.9*Lc)/Lc)]
    # Expected : [0.9, 0.986709867, 0.8] (or something like that)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is:

```
In [33]: m = 0.9

In [34]: Lc = Symbol('Lc')

In [35]: rend = 0.8

In [36]: f = tanh(m*Lc)/(m*Lc)-rend

In [37]: f
Out[37]: 
       1.11111111111111⋅tanh(0.9⋅Lc)
-0.8 + ─────────────────────────────
                     Lc
```

The `solve` function is intended to find analytic solutions but that is often impossible for a transcendental equation such as this.

You are calling `solve` and asking it to solve for `m` and `rend` as well which is just confusing things. You should call it like:

```
In [38]: solve(f, Lc)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError
...
NotImplementedError: multiple generators [Lc, exp(Lc/10)]
No algorithms are implemented to solve equation -4/5 + 10*(exp(9*Lc/10) - exp(-9*Lc/10))/(9*Lc*(exp(9*Lc/10) + exp(-9*Lc/10)))
```

This fails because the transcendental equation can not be solved in explicit analytic form.

Instead if what you want is a numeric solution you can find that using `nsolve`:

```
In [41]: nsolve(f, Lc, 1)
Out[41]: 0.986683032622042

In [42]: nsolve(f, Lc, -1)
Out[42]: -0.986683032622042
```

Here we have to use an initial guess (e.g. 1 or -1) to seed the numeric solver but then we get a numeric answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would vote you up but unfortunately it seems I do not have enough reputation hahah againt thanks a lot.